# Apache Forbidden error on clean CentOS install

Tags: apache, centos, http-status-code-403

I have a clean copy of CentOS.

Just installed Apache, PHP and MySQL. Everything works like a charm.

Except for I created a new user, let's call it 'demo'.

I created a new virtual directory in httpd.conf and pointed it to '/home/demo/www'. I created an empty index.html under '/home/demo/www'.

Apache is running under user 'apache' and group 'apache'.

Maybe user 'apache' does not have access to user 'demo's file, that's why I get the Forbidden problem?

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

James

Comment: You really should add some details: htaccess , owner/permissions of your files etc.
Did you already check permission problems ?

Comment: Owner of the new virtual directory is user 'demo'. Apache is running as user 'apache'.

Yes, I think this might be a permission problem. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: usually apache just needs to read from files and usually the permission is read access granted for all. You can do a "chown -R apache:apache /home/demo/www" to change ownership to apache

Comment: Still not working. So changed back the ownership to demo:demo. Here is the httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/m2fe5114b

Comment: Did you check for a trailing slash problem?

Comment: In case of SELinux could be a trouble of extended permissions, so a quick way to fix this could be **chcon -R --reference=/var/www /path/to/webroot**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to give a 'chmod 755' to '/home/demo'.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your config files It is difficult to find the right spot, 
however Apache will not show 403 if he does not have permissions on files.

403 means *the client*(your browser) has not a permission to view the content

I think you have a [trailing slash](http://planetozh.com/blog/2004/05/apache-and-the-trailing-slash-problem/) problem. Just try this code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hello@demosite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/demo/www/
    ServerName DemoSite
    ErrorLog logs/sb-error_log
    CustomLog logs/sb-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
<Directory "/home/demo/www">
   # Allow open access:
   Require all granted
/Directory>
```

To your Virtual Host definition.